# Problem VHDL process maintaing a signal modified

Tags: vhdl, counter

I am writing a VHDL code of a simple counter which receives as an input a number and that is a time in ms, and a 50 MHz clock, for example if 200 is received it has to count 200 ms so 200* 50e3 cycles, then it has to give an output named Terminal_count_end that has to remain high until a new reset signal is given (which by the way is active when '0')

I created a testbench to test it and i discovered that Terminal_count_end becomes 1 but only for one period of the clock, then it returns to 0 forever.

I am a begginer in VHDL and I really don't know what's I am doing wrong so I thank in advance anyone who can help me with this code!

The code is:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter_start is 
    generic (N : integer := 16);
    port    (enable,clearn, Clk : in std_logic;
            end_time_ms : in unsigned (7 downto 0);
            Terminal_count_end : out std_logic);    
end counter_start;

architecture behavior of counter_start is

signal count : unsigned (N-1 downto 0); 
signal cifra : unsigned (3 downto 0);
signal T_c : std_logic;
signal T_c_end : std_logic;

begin
    process(clk,clearn)
    begin
        if clearn = '0' then
            T_c <= '0';   
            count <= (others => '0');
        elsif (Clk'event and clk = '1') then
            if  T_c = '1' then
                T_c <= '0';
                count <= (others => '0');
            elsif (enable = '1') then
                count <= count + 1;
                if count = to_unsigned(49999, N) then
                    T_c <= '1';
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    cifra_process: process(clk,clearn)
    begin
        if clearn = '0' then
            cifra <= "0000";
            t_c_end <= '0';
        elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
            if (T_c = '1') then
                cifra <= cifra + 1;
                if cifra = end_time_ms-1 then
                        cifra <= "0000";
                        T_c_end <= '1'; 
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    terminal_count_end <= T_c_end;
end behavior;
```

Comment: You should post the testbench as well.

Comment: This question can only be answered with the testbench in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cifra` keeps advancing, and you are checking `=`.

FYI, using async clear is not good practice in modern FPGAs if that's your future target.

Comment: thank you for the answer! i stupidly thought that if nobody changed it it would remain 1 but it make sense that I have to create a condition which is valid for every clock'event, anyway i'm using an async reset because we have a old cyclone II at university with some push buttons and it was written on the text of the exercise, anyway thanks for the information

Comment: You can check `T_c` and `not T_c_end` instead as your enable for that section of `cifra_process`. Also, it is good etiquette to upvote and check the answer if satisfied.

Comment: This is wrong. Only a signal assignment   of '0' to `T_c_end` can reset this flipflop. And such a signal assignment only happens when `clearn` is '0'. The error must be in the testbench which is the only driver of `clearn`.

Comment: @Diro The signal `T_c_end` keeps '1' until you assign a different value to it. And this happens only in the asynchronous reset part when `clearn` is '0'. Thus the error must be in your testbench.